# Technique to validate foreign keys, MVC web application, MySQL

Tags: mysql, model-view-controller, foreign-keys

Having two database tables:

orders (id, client_id, ...) - stores orders of customers

addresses (id, client_id, ...) - stores delivery addresses of customers

Relationship between that tables is many-to-many so I have table

addresses_orders (id, order_id, address_id) which maps where order goes

But I'd like to enforce one thing - in table
addresses_orders can only be paired together orders and addresses of the same customer.

What is the best way to do this?

I have web application based on MVC, which stores data in MySQL database.
Every customer gets only his orders and addresses to choose from, but form can be tampered and malicious user can change address_id to random guess, so it will produce described insonsitency.

For safety I have to validate against this scenario - probably in Model or directly in database.
I prefer second solution, but how to do this? Maybe some triggers?

Comment: Can there be multiple clients at same address ?

Comment: No, each client has his own addresses.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no overlap in addresses ( only one client per address ), Then your DB structure makes no sense.

```
Clients         Addresses         Orders
---             -------           -------
client_id PK    address_id PK     order_id PK
name            client_id FK      address_id FK
phone_number    full_address      data
```

Then to get all details from an order

```
SELECT 
    Clients.name
    Addresses.full_address
    Orders.data
FROM Orders
    LEFT JOIN Addresses USING(address_id)
    LEFT JOIN Clients USING(client_id)
WHERE 
    client_id = 42
```

This would give you all orders from client with ID 42.

- each `order` has one `address`
- each `address` has one `client`
- each `client` has multiple `addresses`
- each `address` has multiple `orders`

Answer (score 0):

Is the `address_id` hidden or visible form field and you are worried that users are capable or willing to mess with it?

I'm guessing your customers are logged in. You could take advantage of session information and `user_id` (or something). Retrieve the customers `address_id` in the process file and use that `address_id`, not the id sent by form (you could of course check if they match). If something goes wrong the problem is probably somewhere in session/application security, but not in the spoofed form.

Answer (score 0):

We tend to use the following approach:

a) Store the customerid in the session

b) When selecting the orders or addresses use one of the following showing the user names while saving the ids:
- A pregenerated list using a select control where only one can be selected
- A pre-generated list from which specific items can be selected using checkboxes